# Chrome browser changing styles after Version 77 update

Tags: css, google-chrome

Chrome browser is changing my style sheet on my webpage. The image attached indicates the color computed using the inspector in Chrome browser, should be white, but black is being displayed. I speculate that the browser was using its own style sheet but from my reading, [Chrome had discontinued using their own style sheets.](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/computer-accessibility/how-to-use-a-custom-style-sheet-css-with-google-chrome/)

I have already tried turning off the Meyer's reset but that hasn't worked. Setting the event types in css explicitly `a:visited, a:active` hasn't worked.

Toggling the visited and active event, in Chrome inspector, for `a:visited` does show that the black color is defaulted but doesn't turn off when toggled back, even when there is a defaulted value for the anchor color is explicitly given.

[image: Chrome showing incorrect color]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting  value `-webkit-text-fill-color:` set the the default value back to white. This wasn't obvious using the inspector and only found having played around with values. This value is set in the Meyers reset but even when the reset was commented out, the color remained black.

I just set the anchor value to  `a{-webkit-text-fill-color: inherit;}`